# Golang access nested element on Json

Tags: go

I have the following golang code which trying to access elements on array my expectation to print bxar ,but it throw error any idea?

```golang
package main
    
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Args struct {
        Foo string
    }
}

func main() {
    in := `[{"args": {"foo": "bar"}},{"args": {"foo": "bxar"}}]}`

    var d []Data
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &d)

    fmt.Println("Foo:", d[1].Args.Foo)
    //fmt.Printf("Result: %+v", d)
}
```

Comment: Do not ignore errors. The program panics because you didn’t handle the error from Unmarshal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it does not work is a typo. There is one too many `}` in your JSON:

Before:

```
`[{"args": {"foo": "bar"}},{"args": {"foo": "bxar"}}]}`
```

After:

```
`[{"args": {"foo": "bar"}},{"args": {"foo": "bxar"}}]`
```

See this playground: https://go.dev/play/p/sL8Cx8lF6WR

Comment: To check for the error, you could assign the result of `json.Unmarshal` into a variable and check / print its value.